# A wikipedia web framework?

Tags: open-source, wiki, web-frameworks

Hey guys we want to create a informational type site for a very precise domain of knowledge, we want it to be in wiki like form. Whereby I mean the informational for each entity of knowledge is created by the users, and it works like wikipedia in that sense. Are there are web libraries we can use for a out of the box solution. WE don't want to spend much time programming this.

Thanks alot :)

Comment: What about using [the software that Wikipedia runs on](http://www.mediawiki.org)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wikipedia is based on the open source [Mediawiki](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki) system.

It's easy to use and install, but not very friendly for complex administration (especially regarding rights). And the editor is fine for engineers, not for everybody.

For other solutions, I suggest you google for "wiki" : that's the generic term describing this kind of system. Or "CMS" for something a little wider.